# linked list vs arrays for dictionaries

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures, analysis

I was recently asked in an interview about `advantages and disadvantages of linked list and arrays for dictionary of words implementation` and also `what is the best data structure for implementing it?` This where I messed up things. After googling I couldn't specifically found exact answer that is specific to dictionaries but general linked list v arrays explanation. **What is the best suited answer to above question?**

Answer (score 3):

If you're just going to use it for lookups, then an array is the obvious best choice of the two. You can build the dictionary from a list of words in O(n log n)--just build an array and sort it. Lookups are O(log n) with a binary search.

Although you can build a linked list of words in O(n), lookups will require, on average, that you look at n/2 words. The difference is pretty large. Given an English dictionary of 128K words, a linked list lookup will take on average 64,000 string comparisons. A binary search will require *at most* 17.

In addition, a linked list of n words will occupy more memory than an array of n words, because you need the `next` pointer in the list.

If you need the ability to update the dictionary, you'll probably still want to use an array if updates are infrequent compared to lookups (which is almost certainly the case). I can't think of a real-world example of a dictionary of words that's updated more frequently than it's queried.

As others have pointed out, neither array nor linked list is the *best* choice for a dictionary of words. But of the two options you're given, array is superior in almost all cases.

Answer (score 1):

There is no one answer.

The two obvious choices would be something based on a hash table if you only want to look up individual items, or something based on a balanced tree if you want to look up ranges of items.

A sorted array can work well if you do a lot of searching and relatively little insertion or deletion. Finding situations where linked lists are preferred is rather more difficult. Depending on the situation (especially such things as finding all the words that start with, say, "ste"), tries can also work extremely well (and often do well at minimizing the storage needed for a given set of data as well).

Those are really broad categories though, not specific implementations. There are also variations such as extensible hashing and distributed hash tables that can be useful in specific situations (and also have somewhat tree-like properties, so things like range-based searching can be reasonable efficient).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're building a dictionary, you'd want it to be a sorted structure. So you're going for a sorted-array or a sorted linked-list.

- For a linked list retrieval is `O(n)` since you have to examine all words until you find the one you need. For a sorted array, you can use binary search to find the right location, which is `O(log n)`.
- For a sorted array, **insertion** is `O(log n)` to find the right location (binary search) and then `O(n)` to insert because you need to push everything down. For a linked list, it would be `O(n)` to find the location and then `O(1)` to insert because you only have to adjust pointers. The same applies for **deletion**.

Since you aren't going to be updating a dictionary much, you can just build and then sort the array in `O(nlog n)` time (using quicksort for example). After that, lookup is `O(log n)` using binary search. Furthermore, as delnan mentioned below, using an array has the advantage that everything you access is sequential in memory; i.e., the data are localized (locality of reference). This minimizes cache misses (which are expensive). With a linked list, the data are spread out all over and there is no guarantee that they are close together, which increases the chance of cache-misses. With this in mind, given the two options, use the **array**.

You can do an even better job if you implement a sorted hashmap using a red-black tree (your tree entries, which are the keys can be coupled with a hashmap); here search, insert, and delete are `O(log n)`. But it really depends on your behavior profile; if you're only doing lookup, a simple hashmap would be best (`O(1)` retrieval).

Another interesting data-structure you can use is a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie), where insertion and lookup are `O(m)`; `m` being the length of the string.

Comment: your this point `For an array, insertion is O(n) to find the right location and then O(n) to insert because you need to push everything down. For a linked list, it would be O(n) to find the location and then O(n) to insert because you only have to adjust pointers.` is a bit confusing. `O(n)` is for both linked list and array finding right location and insertion? O(n) for both? Could you please elaborate?

Comment: @26ph19 Sorry, that was a typo! It should be `O(1)`; editing.

Comment: I really don't see how you can conclude that a linked list is a better option than an array, at least from the facts you presented. Asymptotic complexity is exactly the same. That the actual list manipulation after finding the location to insert is O(1) doesn't matter since the insertion is O(n) overall, at best this would be a constant factory of 1/2 but when you start considering constant factors the array wins hands down.

Comment: @delnan I was actually a little unsure about that part. Can you explain how the constant factors win out? Assuming that you always insert something at the middle of the list, you would have `O(n/2) + O(1)`, whereas for an array it becomes `O(n) + O(n)`. Please let me know how I'm messing up so I can correct the answer!

Comment: The asymptotic bounds you give are correct (well actually array would be `O(n/2) + O(n)` under the same assumption), and the constant factors of the linked list include a 1/2 and the constant factors of the array include a 2 or so. But there's many other constant factors in addition to those. Principally, a linked list will generally cause tons of cache misses, while an array (traversed sequentially) will hit the cache. Both theory and empirical experiments show time and time again that arrays win out even for quite large data sets.

Comment: @delnan Ah, ok I see what you are seeing. So the problem is with cache-misses due to a lack of locality with the data that you're accessing. That makes sense. Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: You specifically said a *sorted* array. Retrieval from a sorted array is O(log n) if you use binary search. Insertion, then, would be O(log n) + O(n).

Comment: @JimMischel How silly of me. You're absolutely right. I should not have assumed linear search.

Answer (score 0):

Best data structure for implementing dictionaries is `suffix trees`. You can also have a look at `tries`.